# How to tie large numbers of ground wires together?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding

I've got a (metal, 2-gang) box for my furnace local shut-off. One gang is currently unused. I'm wanting to install a second toggle switch on the same circuit to control furnace accessories (electronic air cleaner, UV lamp for the A/C coil). When done, that will leave me needing to tie six (12-gauge) ground wires together: One to each load, one to each switch, one to the ground screw on the box itself, and one coming in from the subpanel. That's an awkward number to attempt to connect with a wire nut. I know that there's a better solution; I've seen photos of it (kind of like a terminal block), but I don't know what it's called. Can you help me?

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you mean a lever nut , sometimes called a 'wago' connector after a manufacturer of that style of connector. There's both 'bus' and 'inline' styles. These are images of [inline](https://amzn.to/3Mu07Cg) and [regular](https://amzn.to/3IchULI) UL-listed Wago connectors from Amazon. Make sure you get only use UL or ETL listed connectors.

[image: Wago inline]

[image: Wago regular]

Answer (score 3):

If that's a metal box, with the screws screwing into the box, a mud ring or domed cover, then **you do not need ground wires to the switches**.

That cuts your number down to four, and you're well within the reach of a wire nut or 4-5 port Wago.  Don't forget the greenie "ground" wire nuts that allows you to extend one of the ground wires through the nut, and then you can land that on the screw.

By the way, receptacles can do the same trick if one of these things are true:

- The receptacle's yoke (frame) makes hard flush clean-metal contact with the box (or  domed cover or mud ring, if that does the same to the box itself).
- the receptacle is floating above the metal box on the drywall ears, *but*, the receptacle is labeled "Self-Grounding".

Comment: Does a receptacle *not* labeled Self Grounding necessarily ground legally "yoke to box"?

Comment: As a DIY-er, I would go with this answer.  I know the kind of connector you are referring to @ehbowen, I have one in a large junction box that was installed by an electrician.  But even though it's not that hard, I wouldn't bother figuring out where to buy and how to *correctly* use one, for the first and probably last time in my life, when all the methods in this answer are cheap, easy, and already familiar to me.

Comment: @manassehkatz Yes, anything  can use the "hard flush metal/metal contact" method.  Receptalces only needs self-grounding (wiper on screws) if they are floating proud of the box e.g. by the drywall ears.  Switches do not need self-grounding.